# Como ter mais precisão no GPS usando google location no android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-location-api

No meu projeto, eu preciso obter uma localização atual do usuário e o endereço e atualizar constantemente minha posição por causa de uma maior precisão. O problema é que, quando eu consegui a localização (Latitude e Longitude), usando a classe Geocode para obter o endereço e exibir com um marcador, ele mostra o endereço errado, e alguns segundos depois mostra o endereço certo, eu queria saber se o problema é Meu dispositivo Android ou meu código! É assim que eu fiz!

**Chamo a conexão**

```
private synchronized void callConnection() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

**O OnConnected**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i("LOG", "onConnected(" + bundle + ")");
    try{
        Location l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(l != null){
            Log.i("LOG","latitude: " + l.getLatitude());
            Log.i("LOG","longitude: " + l.getLongitude());

            lat =  l.getLatitude();
            lon = l.getLongitude();
            mapUpdate(lat,lon);
        }
        address = getAddress(lat,lon);
        Log.i("LOG","city: " + address.getLocality());
        Log.i("LOG","state: " + address.getAdminArea());
        Log.i("LOG","country: " + address.getCountryName());
        Log.i("LOG","address: " + address.getAddressLine(0));
        Log.i("LOG","getThoroughfare" + address.getThoroughfare());
        Log.i("LOG","FT" + address.getFeatureName());
        ads = address.getAddressLine(0);
        startLocationUpdate();
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Método para retornar o endereço**

```
private Address getAddress(double lat, double lon) throws IOException{
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Address address = null;
    List<Address> addressList;

    geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lon,1);
    if(addressList.size() > 0){
        address = addressList.get(0);
    }
    return address;
}
```

**E o método para atualizar o mapa**

```
private void mapUpdate(final Double lat,final Double lon){
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Log.i("LOG",googleMap.toString());
            mMap = googleMap;

            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            LatLng myCurrentLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            if(marker == null){
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myCurrentLocation).title(ads));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCurrentLocation, 20));
                marker.showInfoWindow();

            }else {
                marker.setPosition(myCurrentLocation);
                marker.setTitle(getLastAddress(lat,lon));
                marker.showInfoWindow();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Agora eu atualizo a localização porque o usuário pode se mover e ter melhor qualidade**

```
private void initLocationRequest(){

    mlocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mlocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mlocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
    mlocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
private void startLocationUpdate(){

    initLocationRequest();
    try{
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mlocationRequest,MainActivity.this);
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("LOG","latitude(" + location.getLatitude());
    Log.i("LOG","longitude" + location.getLongitude());
    Log.i("LOG","speed" + location.getSpeed());

    lat =  location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
    mapUpdate(lat,lon);
    //stopLocation();
}
```

**Todo vez que mudar, eu mudo também o endereço e passo dentro do Maker!**

```
private String getLastAddress(double lat, double lon){
    try {
        address = getAddress(lat,lon);
        ads = address.getAddressLine(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ads;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

sempre volta primeiro a localização mais atual que foi registrada no aparelho pela GooglePlayServices. Se quiser pegar a localização atual primeiro, você deve ignorar esta primeira localização e utilizar sempre a mais recente, recebida no seu método startLocationUpdate

Referência:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)